# Selecting Ranges in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a VBA subroutine that searches a table for the first column header named "Phonetic Name". Then finds the absolute last cell in the table, on the bottom right corner, and store a variable as the cell coordinate one row above the last cell. The subroutine would then select all cells between the first cell "Phonetic Name" and the "LastCell" variable.

```
Dim LastCol As Integer

TL = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("Phonetic Name", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Row

Set LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)

With ActiveSheet
    LastCol = .Cells(TL, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow.Row - 1, LastCol)
'I would like to do something like the following... 
ActiveSheet.Range("TL:LastCell").Select
Selection.Copy
```

How can I re-write this logic in a way that is VBA friendly?

Comment: What's wrong with that code ?

Comment: I think `ActiveSheet.Range(TL,LastCell).Copy` is what you're looking for (but remove the `.Row` from the end of the `.Find()` line)

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim LastCol As Integer  
Dim TL as Range

Set TL = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find("Phonetic Name", _
                 LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)  

If Not TL Is Nothing Then

    Set LastRow = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)  
    With ActiveSheet     
        LastCol = .Cells(TL.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
    End With  
    Set LastCell = ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow.Row - 1, LastCol) 
    ActiveSheet.Range(TL,LastCell).Copy

End If
```

Comment: Change TL to TL.Row, i.e., `LastCol = .Cells(TL, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` to 
 `LastCol = .Cells(TL.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`  Also, consider expanding your With statement to include all ActiveSheet references, and declaring all your variables.